# Codesign related error while performing SonarQube xcode build wrapper: build-wrapper-macosx-x86

Tags: xcode, macos, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, codesign

I followed this guide: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/SonarCFamily+for+Objective-C

However, when performing xcodebuild with the wrapper:

```
build-wrapper-macosx-x86 --out-dir ./bw_output xcrun xcodebuild
```

I get the following error:

```
dyld: warning: could not load inserted library 'somepath/libinterceptor.dylib' into library validated process because no suitable image found.  Did find:
    somepath/libinterceptor.dylib: code signing blocked mmap() of 'somepath/build-wrapper-macosx-x86/libinterceptor.dylib'
    somepath/libinterceptor.dylib: stat() failed with errno=1
```

It seems to be related to the lack of a codesignature being present for the libinterceptor.dylib. (codesign -v verifies this).

How can I get a signed version of this wrapper or force MacOSX to load this unsigned library?

Comment: Is is just a `warning` or is it actually failing something ? I recommend you make sure to use [latest version](https://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=7996665) (also of _build-wrapper_) and also review ticket [CPP-1640](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/CPP-1640)